# Silverlight ListBox does not scroll on mouse wheel movement on Mac

Tags: macos, silverlight, listbox, scrollviewer, mousewheel

I have Silverlight based web app where. I found the ListBox doesn't scroll on mouse wheel scroll. I am able to scroll by clicking vertical scroll bar. When I use mouse wheel or 2 finger scroll it doesn't work. 
Here in Mouse Wheel scroll in List box 2 is working fine but ListBox 1 it does not work.

**ListBox 1**

```
<Border CornerRadius="6,6,0,0" Grid.Row="1" Margin="2,5,2,0" BorderThickness="1,1,1,0" BorderBrush="#FFC4C4C4">
<Grid>
      <ListBox x:Name="filterListBox" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Background="Transparent" SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedFilterIndex, Mode=TwoWay}"  SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedFilterItem, Mode=TwoWay}" SelectionChanged="ListBox_SelectionChanged"  BorderThickness="0" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="5,3" ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource FilterListBoxItemStyle}">
                    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                        <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
                            <ei:CallMethodAction TargetObject="{Binding}" MethodName="FilterSelectionChanged"/>
                        </i:EventTrigger>
                    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                    <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
                        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                    <ListBoxItem Padding="7,2" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Tag="Popular" Visibility="{Binding Path=IsPopularChannelTab, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibilityConverter}}">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=PopularChannelsText, Source={StaticResource PageStrings}}" FontSize="13" FontWeight="SemiBold" FontFamily="Arial" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                        </ListBoxItem>
                    <ListBoxItem  IsEnabled="False" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Visibility="{Binding Path=IsPopularChannelTab, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibilityConverter}}">
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <Border BorderBrush="#FFBDBDBD" BorderThickness="0,2,2,2" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Height="20"/>
                                <Border BorderBrush="#FFF8F8F8" BorderThickness="0,2,2,2" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Height="20"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </ListBoxItem>
                    <ListBoxItem Padding="7,2" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Tag="All">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=AllChannelsText, Source={StaticResource PageStrings}}" FontSize="12" FontWeight="SemiBold" FontFamily="Arial" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                    </ListBoxItem>
                    <ListBoxItem  IsEnabled="False" VerticalContentAlignment="Center">
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <Border BorderBrush="#FFBDBDBD" BorderThickness="0,2,2,2" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"  Height="20"/>
                            <Border BorderBrush="#FFF8F8F8" BorderThickness="0,2,2,2" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Height="20"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </ListBoxItem>
                    <ListBoxItem Padding="7,2" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Tag="Favorites">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=FavoritesText, Source={StaticResource PageStrings}}" FontSize="13" FontWeight="SemiBold" FontFamily="Arial" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                    </ListBoxItem>

                </ListBox>
</Grid>
</Border>
```

**ListBox 2**

```
<Grid Visibility="{Binding Path=IsHavingProvider, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibilityConverter}}" Margin="0,20,0,0" Grid.Row="4">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="18"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                <core:MagicTextBlock Grid.Row="0" TextBlockStyle="{StaticResource TextBlock_Style}" Text="{Binding Path=Activity, Source={StaticResource PageStrings}}" />

                <ListBox Margin="0,10,0,0" Grid.Row="1"  x:Name="Provider" Width="480" Height="195" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
                    ItemsSource="{Binding Providers,Mode=TwoWay}"
                    SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedProvider,Mode=TwoWay}"
                    ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource Table_ListBoxItem_Style}"
                    DisplayMemberPath="name">
                </ListBox>
            </Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to be the bearer of bad news:

> Some current mouse devices for Macintosh have a physical or virtual
>   mouse wheel. However, the program access layer used by Silverlight on
>   Macintosh does not support forwarding the mousewheel event to
>   Silverlight in a browser-hosted situation. You can handle the
>   Silverlight MouseWheel event from a Macintosh platform client, if the
>   Silverlight application is running out-of-browser. Otherwise, consider
>   handling mousewheel events for Macintosh platform at the HTML DOM
>   level; for more information, see Platform Dependencies.

From the MSDN [Silverlight Differences on Windows and Macintosh](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc838247%28v=vs.95%29.aspx).

The good news is you can listen to the mousewheel events in the HTML page via JavaScript and pass those events into Silverlight via its [JavaScript interop API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221414%28v=vs.95%29.aspx). The additional bad news is I don't know of a way to have it automatically wire into the GUI elements in your application to have them automatically *just work* (like scrolling list boxes in your case). As far as I know, you'd have to manually listen to it, pick up on which object the user is hovering over with their mouse, and programmatically scroll the GUI component.

Comment: but for some list box it works fine.Listbox 2 in my case is working fine without HTML bridge

Comment: @Chris_vr: Sorry, my mistake misreading the question. Try making the background for the listbox non-transparent and that the mouse cursor is over some visibly physical piece of its content before mouse-wheeling.

Comment: :I noticed it is only with safari.It is working fine with Firefox in Mac

Comment: @Chris_vr: I suspect this is just one of the lovely issues of the Silverlight plugin, probably related to the MSDN article I posted. The only _other_, grasping-at-straws idea I have is to try toggling the `Windowless` mode setting. (But again, just grasping at straws; I'm not even sure if it works on Mac+Safari)